# data preparation for seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, seaborn, sklearn-pandas

I have a data frame with 50 column and 11000 rows and I want to predict salary.
https://www.kaggle.com/kaggle/kaggle-survey-2018
this is how my encoded data look like:

[image]
First of all, I did the data cleaning and then the data encoding with sklearn. my target variable is the salary (df['Q9']) and I chose it as 'y'.
Thus, I assigned all other columns of my data frame as 'x'.

```
y=df_encoded['Q9']
x=df_encoded.drop(['Q9'], axis=1)
```

y contains integer and the x has strings. There is no NAN inside the dataframe.
code for heat map:

```
f,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 18))
sns.heatmap(x.corr(), annot=True, linewidths=.5, fmt= '.1f',ax=ax)
```

I wanted to plot a seaborn heat map but I received this error:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------

-----
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-049cf9365602> in <module>()
      1 f,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 18))
----> 2 sns.heatmap(x.corr(), annot=True, linewidths=.5, fmt= '.1f',ax=ax)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/seaborn/matrix.py in heatmap(data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, annot, fmt, annot_kws, linewidths, linecolor, cbar, cbar_kws, cbar_ax, square, xticklabels, yticklabels, mask, ax, **kwargs)
    515     plotter = _HeatMapper(data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, annot, fmt,
    516                           annot_kws, cbar, cbar_kws, xticklabels,
--> 517                           yticklabels, mask)
    518 
    519     # Add the pcolormesh kwargs here

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/seaborn/matrix.py in __init__(self, data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, annot, fmt, annot_kws, cbar, cbar_kws, xticklabels, yticklabels, mask)
    166         # Determine good default values for the colormapping
    167         self._determine_cmap_params(plot_data, vmin, vmax,
--> 168                                     cmap, center, robust)
    169 
    170         # Sort out the annotations

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/seaborn/matrix.py in _determine_cmap_params(self, plot_data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust)
    205         calc_data = plot_data.data[~np.isnan(plot_data.data)]
    206         if vmin is None:
--> 207             vmin = np.percentile(calc_data, 2) if robust else calc_data.min()
    208         if vmax is None:
    209             vmax = np.percentile(calc_data, 98) if robust else calc_data.max()

/resources/common/.virtualenv/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in _amin(a, axis, out, keepdims)
     27 
     28 def _amin(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
---> 29     return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
     30 
     31 def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):

ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
```

I have searched about this error and I think my data needs to pivot! but I don't have any idea how to do it and what is that!!

Comment: Can you print `x.corr()`?

Comment: @FChm when I enter x.corr() there is no error but nothing will be shown

Comment: Are you printing it?

Comment: @FChm when I printed, I got this: Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []

Comment: I imagine the type of your columns are not numeric.

Comment: @FChm yeah, they are object. I have searched about it and I think I should change them to float. but I have 2 questions. 1) my data is encoded now, is that ok to change them to float? how can I decode it if it is float. 2) I tried df_encoded.astype(float) but there is an value error for it